# Make a gif animation repeat (loop) in a div

Tags: jquery, css

I need to animate a few div elements using the same gif, every time the mouse is on hover. I'm using css `:hover`, the but animation plays just one time. How can I make it play continuously?

Example for experiments: http://jsfiddle.net/mbarinov/9xymF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with an img tag

```
<div><img /></div>
<div><img /></div>

$('div').mouseover(function() {
    $('img', this).attr('src', 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3935026/central_bg_hover.gif');
});
```